# Watson Speech to Text empty result

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am running the following app code in Bluemix, to return the text from an audio file however I don't get any result or error.

Any idea?

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud')
var fs = require('fs')

var speech_to_text = watson.speech_to_text({
  version: "v1",
  url: "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api",
  password: "********",
  username: "*********"
})

var params = {
  audio: fs.createReadStream('./01_Ge_S_01.ogg'),
  content_type: 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus',
  continuous: true,
  model: 'es-ES_BroadbandModel'
}

speech_to_text.recognize(params, function(err, res){
  if (err)
    console.log(err)
  else
    fs.writeFile('public/result.txt', JSON.stringify(res))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))

})
```

Comment: Hi @daniel can you make the ogg file available somewhere? (google drive maybe?)

Comment: Also, do not expose your credentials in the post!

Comment: which version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: The file is here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3hUA9ZiaktrM2NBYm1XcWpzRGM/view?usp=sharing

And the SDK version is

IBM SDK for Node.js Buildpack v3.1-20160222-1123

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is related to file conversion. The original file is mp3 extension however because speech to text API doesn't work mp3 I converted the file to ogg or wav using ffmpeg but both of them are not showing results.

Comment: try to use the API directly with the [API Explorer](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/speech-to-text-v1#!/sessionless/recognizeSessionless)

Comment: I tried the same file on API Explorer and didn't work. However using the same file on this demo https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/ it worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your problem but I'm able to run your code with some small changes.

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');
var speechToText = watson.speech_to_text({
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api',
  username: 'SPEECH TO TEXT USERNAME',
  password: 'SPEECH TO TEXT PASSWORD',
  version: 'v1'
});

var params = {
  audio: fs.createReadStream('./01_Ge_S_01.ogg'),
  content_type: 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus',
  continuous: true,
  model: 'es-ES_BroadbandModel'
};

speechToText.recognize(params, function(err, res){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    var transcriptJson = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('result.json', transcriptJson);

    var transcription = '';
    res.results.forEach(function(e) {
      transcription+= e.alternatives[0].transcript + '\n';
    });
    fs.writeFileSync('result.txt', transcription);
    console.log(transcription);
  }
});
```

The transcription for `01_Fe_S_01.ogg` is:

```
génesis
capítulo uno
en el principio creó dios los cielos y la tierra
ahora bien
la tierra resultó sin forma y de cierta
y había oscuridad sobre las superficies de la profundidad acuosa
y la fuerza activa de dios
estaba moviéndose de un lado a otro sobre la superficie de las aguas
y procedió diosa decidir
llegue a haber luz
entonces
llegó a verlo
después de eso
vio dios que la luz era buena
y f tuvo dios una división entre la luz
y la oscuridad
y empezó a dios a llamar la luz día
pero a la oscuridad
llamó noche
y llegó a haber tarde
y llegó a ver mañana
un día
primero
y pasó diosa decidir
llegue a haber una expansión en medio de las aguas
y ocurra una división entre las aguas y las aguas
entonces
procedió diosa hacer la expansión
y hacer una división entre las aguas que deberían estar debajo de la expansión
y las aguas que deberían estar sobre la expansión
y llegó a ser así
y empezó diosa llamar la expansión cielo
y llegó a haber tarde
y llegó a ver mañana
un día
segundo
y pasó diosa decir
que las aguas debajo de los cielos se reúnan en un mismo lugar
y aparezca lo seco
y llegó a ser así
y empezó diosa llamarlos seco tierra
pero a la reunión de aguas
llamó mares
además
vio dios que era bueno
y pasó diosa decir
haga brotar la tierra y hierba
vegetación que dé semilla
árboles frutales que lleven frutos según sus géneros
cuya semilla
esté enel sobre la tierra
y llegó a ser así
y la tierra empezó a producir hierba
vegetación queda semillas según su género y árboles que llevan fruto cuya semilla está en el según su género
entonces
vio dios que era bueno
y llegó a ver tarde
y que corra ver mañana
un día
tercero
y pasó diosa define
lleguen a ver lumbreras en la expansión de los cielos
para hacer una división entre el día y la noche
y tienen que servir de señales
y para estaciones
y pararía hacía años
y tienen que servir de lumbreras en la expansión de los cielos
para brillar sobre la tierra
y llegó a ser así
y procedió a dios hacer las dos grandes lumbreras
la lumbrera mayor para dominar el día
y la lumbrera menor para dominar la noche
y también las estrellas
así las puso dios en la expansión de los cielos
para brillar sobre la tierra
y para dominar de día y de noche
y para hacer una división entre la luz y la oscuridad
entonces
vio dios que era bueno
y llegó a acercarse
y llegó a ver mañana
un día
cuarto
y pasó dios al f
enjambre en las aguas un enjambre de almas vivientes
y buen criaturas volátiles por encima de la tierra sobre la faz de la expansión de los cielos
y procedió diosa crear los grandes monstruos marinos
y toda alma viviente que se mueve
cuál es las aguas enjambre aron según sus géneros
y toda criatura volátil aladas según su género
y llegó a ver dios que era bueno
con eso
los bendijo dios diciendo
sean fructíferos y háganse muchos
y llene las aguas en las cuencas de los mares
y avance muchas las criaturas volátiles en la tierra
y llegó a haber tarde
y llegó a haber mañana
un día quinto
y pasó diosa define
produzca la tierra al más viviente según sus géneros
animal doméstico y animal moviéndose y bestia salvaje de la tierra según su género
y llegó a ser así
y procedió diosa hacer la bestia salvaje de la tierra según su género
y el animal doméstico según su género
y todo animal moviento del suelo según su género
y llegó a ver a dios que era
bueno
y pasó dios a veces
hagamos un hombre a nuestra imagen
según nuestra semejanza
y tengan ellos en sujeción los peces del mar
y las criaturas volátiles de los cielos
y los animales domésticos
y toda la tierra y todo animal moviendo de qué se mueve sobre la tierra
y procedió diosa crear al hombre a su imagen
a la imagen de dios lo creo
macho
y en vara los creo
además
los bendijo dios y les dijo dios
sean fructíferos y háganse muchos
y llenen la tierra y sojuzgar la
y tengan sujeción los peces del mar
y las criaturas volátiles de los cielos
y toda criatura viviente que se mueve sobre la tía
y pasó diosa definir
miren que les he dado toda vegetación que la semilla que está sobre la superficie de toda la tierra
y todo árbol en el cual y fruto de árbol que da semilla
que les sirva usted este alimento
que a toda bestia salvaje de la tierra
y a toda criatura volátil de los cielos
y a todo lo que se mueve sobre la tierra en que a ibiza como alma
les he dado toda la vegetación verde para alimento
y llegó a ser así
después de eso
vio dios todo lo que había hecho y
mire
era muy bueno
y llegó a haber tarde
y llegó a ver mañana
un día
sexto
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is the usage of writeFile vs. writeFileSync.

As writeFile is async and was not passed with the callback, it might be returning immediately, and no error or success will be printed.

writeFileSync waits for the file write to complete, and blocks the thread while thus waiting.